# Is it possible to change a whole word into multiple letter variables?

Tags: python

In Python would I be able to split a whole word into multiple letter variables, for example:

```
word = 'because'
```

Would give:

```
1 = 'b'    
2 = 'e'    
3 = 'c'    
4 = 'a' 
5 = 'u'
6 = 's'
7 = 'e'
```

Comment: No; Python names must start with a letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but you can access the individual characters of a string using indexing:

```
word = "because"
print(word[0])  # Prints "b"
print(word[1])  # Prints "e"
print(word[2])  # Prints "c"
print(word[3])  # Prints "a"
print(word[4])  # Prints "u"
print(word[5])  # Prints "s"
print(word[6])  # Prints "e"
```

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic variables are a bad practice and should be avoided.  It is very easy to lose track of them, accidentally overshadow them, etc.

Why not use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) instead?

```
>>> word = 'because'
>>> dct = dict(enumerate(word, 1))
>>> dct
{1: 'b', 2: 'e', 3: 'c', 4: 'a', 5: 'u', 6: 's', 7: 'e'}
>>> dct[1]  # Would be the same as 'var_1'
'b'
>>> dct[5]  # Would be the same as 'var_5'
'u'
>>>
```

As you can see, it is about the same as dynamic variable names except that the data is stored cleanly in a dictionary object.